# $\text{LOOP-EVEN}_{TM}$ = {M is a TM that won't halt for every EVEN input} why is $\text{LOOP-EVEN}^\complement$ recognisable?

Tags: computability, formal-languages, turing-machines

> Given the language
>
> $\text{LOOP-EVEN}_{TM}$ = {M is a TM that won't halt for every **even**
>   input}
>
> Show that $\text{LOOP-EVEN}^\complement$ is recognizable.

This is the what i think is the proof:

> Let's build a TM that will recognize $\text{LOOP-EVEN}^\complement$, This
>   machine will contain all TMs M' that have at least one even input that
>   halts. Let's run in parallel all even words on M' and if one halts
>   then accept M'.

If i am correct in my proof then what i do not understand is how running in parallel can work on a language in case it is infinite?
how would a round robin algorithm work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof sketch works.

There are two classical ways to run infinitely many Turing machine instances in parallel, looking for one that terminates.

**The first way** is often known as "dovetailing". Interlace the steps of all the machines you simulate as follows:

- At times $1, 3, 5, 7, 9, \ldots$ do a step of computation number $0$.
- At times $2, 6, 10, 14, 18, \ldots$ do a step of computation number $1$.
- At times $4, 12, 20, 28, 36, \ldots$ do a step of computation number $2$.
- And so forth. In general when the time is an *odd* multiple of $2^n$, do a step of computation number $n$.

At each finite step in this process, you will only have made the *first* step of finitely many of the computations, so you can remember the *configurations* of all of those for when you get to one of them the next time. On the other hand, if one of the computations eventually terminates, you *will* get to the step where it terminates sooner or later (unless you find another terminating computation first).

**The second way.**

- Let $g$ be your favorite computable surjection $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.
- For $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$, do:

  - Let $(a,b) = g(n)$.
  - Simulate computation number $a$ for $b$ steps (or $2^b$ steps, or some other unbounded function of $b$), starting from the beginning. If it terminates within this time limit, you're done. Otherwise continue with the next $n$.

This is somewhat easier to program, and has better space behavior, but wastes a lot of time redoing steps it has already done once.

On the other hand, *neither* of these "efficiency" considerations matter any as long as we're only interested in *computability*. So authors tend to pick one of the strategies purely based on which they think will be *easiest to explain* to their audience.